# Django tests, verify that a Profile is automatically created

Tags: python, django

thanks in advance, How could I verify that a profile is automatically created after a user creation threw a test? I've searched in the TestCase docs but found nothing but i'm sure I'm missing something really obvious.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from users.models import Profile

class test_user_creation(TestCase):

def test_create_user(self):

    User = get_user_model()

    new_user = User.objects.create_user(
        username="New_user", email="New_user@user.com", date_of_birth="2002-12-23")

    self.assertEqual(new_user.username, "New_user")
    self.assertEqual(new_user.email, "New_user@user.com")
    self.assertEqual(new_user.date_of_birth, "2002-12-23")
    self.assertIs(new_user.is_admin, False)
    self.assertIs(new_user.is_staff, False)
    self.assertEqual(
        new_user.profile, "New_user Profile")
```

**The last one is the one i'm asking about, it's working this way but how could i do it without refering to the string returned by the Profile class ?**

My Profile class

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find it using the manager:

```
self.assertEqual(new_user.profile, Profile.objects.get(user=new_user))
```